# Disabling and enabling VS Code extensions

Tags: visual-studio-code, sonarlint, vscode-tasks

I use vs code for several languages and I have several extensions for each one of them. I have some interrelated  questions to ask about this:
1- Do the extensions take up memory at all times even if they are not needed for the current file? Because I wouldn't want Java and PHP extensions to slow down the editor while I'm working on a JavaScript project for example.
2- Is it possible to disable extensions for certain types of files? Because I use a linter for HTML, JavaScript and React named DeepScan and I have another linter that works with JavaScript, HTML, python, java and PHP named SonarLint but I would not like it to be active on HTML and JavaScript files because I prefer DeepScan. I would like to be able to disable an extension on some file types.
3- Is it possible to disable/enable in one click several extensions at the same time? Example: make a list of several extensions and disable/enable these extensions in one click.
Thanks

Comment: if you don't open a file of a particular type the extension will not be activated, once activated it will be deleted the moment you switch workspace. You can disable extensions on a workspace basis, see extension page

Comment: Ok but can I disable an extension for a certain file type ?